# How to set Direction RTL for PDF invoices Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, multi-language, arabic

I'm using Magento v2.1.3 with two **languages**. The default language is **English** and the other one is **Arabic**. Everything is working properly in **frontend** for the **Arabic Language**. In the **backend**, I'm trying to print the **invoice** in the **Arabic language** with direction **Right to left**. But I'm not getting the way to change the **Direction** for **PDF invoice** to **RTL**. Can you please help me to change the **direction** for the **Arabic** language?

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Yudi got any solution regarding this concern?

Comment: Hey @sanjayVadadoriya, I'm using Tcpdf to export pdf for the invoice. You can use the below code if you are using same.

`$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
$pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 11);
$pdf->setRTL(true);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output("$filename.pdf", 'I');
`

Comment: Hi @Yudi Please you can guide describe the details of changing the above be done? Thank you so very max